# EF Include with populating ViewModel

Tags: entity-framework

While retrieving data with the help of Entity Framework, I would like to populate child ViewModel, which happens to be a collection. The query below works fine, but only populates the inner ViewModel with the first item of the child Model (collection). How can I populate the inner ViewModel with all the corresponding Model data.

```
var pagedQuestions = _ctx.VoteQuestions.Include(q => q.VoteAnswerOptions).Select(q => new Question
{
    QuestionStr = q.Name,
    QuestionId = q.Id,
    IsMultipleAnswerQuestion = q.VoteType.Id == 1 ? false : true,
    PossibleAnswers = new List<PossibleAnswer>
    {
        new PossibleAnswer
        {
            AnswerId = q.VoteAnswerOptions.FirstOrDefault().Id,
            AnswerStr = q.VoteAnswerOptions.FirstOrDefault().Answer
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That code is incomplete, the first line ends abruptly

Comment: it works just fine, I am able to populate data with the code above

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognize the initialization, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a second `Select` inside the first `Select`:

```
var pagedQuestions = _ctx.VoteQuestions.Select(q => new Question
{
    QuestionStr = q.Name,
    QuestionId = q.Id,
    IsMultipleAnswerQuestion = q.VoteType.Id == 1 ? false : true,
    PossibleAnswers = q.VoteAnswerOptions
                       .Select(a => new PossibleAnswer
                                {
                                    AnswerId = a.Id,
                                    AnswerStr = a.Answer
                                }
                              )
    }
});
```

You don't need the `Include`. Entity Framework will join `VoteAnswerOptions` itself and select the required fields from it.